# obscure warning lme4 using lmer in optwrap

Tags: r, lme4

Using `lmer` I get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, x@theta, lower = x@lower) :
  convergence code 3 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- a trust region step failed to reduce q
```

This error ois generated after using `anova(model1, model2)` . I tried to make this reproducible but if I `dput` the data and try again I the error does not reproduce on the dput data, despite the original and new datarames have the exact same `str`.

If have tried again in a clean session, and the error reproduces, and again is lost with a `dput`

I know I am not giving people much to work with here, like i said I would love to reproduce the problem. Cayone shed light on this warning?

Comment: Sounds like `dput` is rounding or truncating some values and the original values are "breaking bad" while the truncated values are able to converge.  Try `orig_data - dput_data` to see what the deltas are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm not sure whether this is a comment or an answer, but it's a bit long and *might* be an answer.)

- The proximal cause of your difficulty with reproducing the result is that `lme4` uses  both environments and reference classes: these are tricky to "serialize", i.e. to translate to a linear stream that can be saved via `dput()` or `save()`.  (Can you please try `save()` and see if it works better than `dput()`?
- In addition, both environments and reference classes use "pass-by-reference" semantics, so operating on the saved model *can* change it. `anova()` automatically refits the model, which makes some tiny but non-zero changes in the internal structure of the saved model object (we are still trying to track this down).
- @alexkeil's comment is wrong: the nonlinear optimizers used within `lme4` do *not* use any calls to the pseudo-random number generator. They are deterministic (but the two points above explain why things might look a bit weird).

To allay your concerns with the fit, I would check the fit by computing the gradient and Hessian at the final fit, e.g.

```
library(lme4)
library(numDeriv)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
dd <- update(fm1,devFunOnly=TRUE)
params <- getME(fm1,"theta") ## also need beta for glmer fits
grad(dd,params)
## all values 'small', say < 1e-3
## [1] 0.0002462423 0.0003276917 0.0003415010
eigen(solve(hessian(dd,params)),only.values=TRUE)$values
## all values positive and of similar magnitude
## [1] 0.029051631 0.002757233 0.001182232
```

We are in the process of implementing similar checks to run automatically within `lme4`.

That said, I would still love to see your example, if there's a way to reproduce it relatively easily.

PS: in order to be using `bobyqa`, you must either be using `glmer` or have used `lmerControl` to modify the default optimizer choice ... ??

Comment: dear Ben, thanks for your comments, I never used `save` so just checking how to use that to try it out. I tried `options=22` and cut/paste but that doesn't reproduce. Promise I am using `lmer`and I have ot knowingly modified the optimizer choice. I am in `R 3.0.2` and `lme4_1.0-5` just in case anyone asks.

Comment: although if I anonymise my data, by changing the names of levels the in `test` where test is : `lmer(ans1 ~  test + (1|z), data = try1)` the warning also stops..